# Python3 most efficient String to Float conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

I extract data from **scrapy** .
There is a string representing a float '   0,18' .
What is the most **efficient** way to convert a String into a float ?

Right now, I convert like this. There are space characters to remove. Comma is replaced by dot.

```
>>> num = '   0,18'
>>> float(num.replace(' ','').replace(',','.'))
0.18
```

I believe my method is far from efficient in time complexity when dealing with tons of data.

Comment: Note: try the `.strip()` method instead of `.replace(' ',’’)`. Also, what do you mean by efficient? Time-wise? Because the builtin `float` function should be fast enough. Using the `timeit.timeit` function, your above code runs a million times in 0.72 seconds.

Comment: @ra thanks for '.strip()' . Yes I mean efficient time wise . I edited the post

Comment: You really can't get more efficient than the built-in `float` function unless you write in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may drop the whitespace stripping.  `float` will eat up whitespace:

```
>>> float('   0.18')
0.18
```

Comment: you forgot about the `replace(',','.')` :) . Otherwise it's a simply effective.

Answer (score 1):

This is okay but if you look at how this is processed, at a high level, there are three function calls, every time:

1. Replace the empty space with nothing
2. Replace the comma with a dot
3. Convert string to float

To simply reduce code, you can get rid of step 1. And just replace the comma with the dot and then convert the string to float.